# Access denied with remote mysql connector python3 connection

Tags: python, mysql

Connection problem solved! Leaving for others who may have issue.

Still having problems with bind-address issues

I will state the problem, the loayout context of my system and things I have tried.

Problem:  When trying to use mysql connector in a python file i keep getting access denied.  I am using Pycharm as my IDE and I have the Mysql connector installed though that.

So I am running Ubuntu Server on a Orale VM on a Windows 10 desktop, it's a bridged connection and I can SSH in from my laptop (LInux Mint)to the server just fine.  I am running the program trying to access the DB on the Linux Mint laptop.  Local network only using 192.168.0.xxx protocols. All VPN's disabled at this point for now.

So just to state i reinstalled the server last night and I set up fresh users and DB for the user and even granted ALL PRIVILEGES to the user and connections from my connectiong machines.
i set bind address in my mysqld.cnf file to 0.0.0.0 for now.
(when i had it set to my laptop ip it wouldn't bind and would restart until I switched it back)

UFW is set to allow mysql(3306)

Ask all the questions and I will get you answers asap.  Please provide commands for me to run if needed and specify if the should be ran on the server or my laptop.  Thanks for reading!

Comment: If the network or firewalls were blocking, you'd get "connection refused" errors. "Access denied" is a privilege error, so this means the network is fine. Your connection request is reaching MySQL Server, and it is responding with a privilege error. So either your user/password is incorrect, or you are trying to access a schema you don't have privilege to see.

Comment: A good test is to try using the `mysql` command line client, not your PyCharm IDE, to test the connection. E.g.: `mysql -h <ubuntu-server> -u <user> -p <schema>` That will prompt you to enter your password. If that works, then you must have misconfigured your PyCharm connector, for instance maybe you didn't set the password correctly.

Comment: Bill thank you!  That led to me realize that when I created another user with a new connection host it does not bring the same password over. Actually there wasn't set at all for that user so i removed the password param and it connected.  I added a password and successfully connected again.  What I did to see was pull the user list and have host, plugin, and authentication_string in addition to user names.  Do you know the difference between setting the bind-address vs mysqlx-bind-address? Do i set them both to the same?  I can only bind to local or 0.0.0.0 at the moment.

Comment: try to create a user that can connect from any host to test like: CREATE USER testuser@'%' ...... the % means that you can connect from any remote host

Comment: The `mysqlx_bind_address` variable controls access to the X protocol port, which is the non-SQL interface in MySQL 8.0 (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/document-store-interfaces.html).

Comment: Thank you, I see that isn't the problem.  I think the mysql server can't see my laptop IP on the network and it's not letting it bind.  Not sure if it's because its running on an Ubuntu VM. I think i'll be ok with 0.0.0.0 for now. Thank you again!